# Which axis of the input of the RNN is used as the "temporal" axis in Keras?

Tags: classification, tensorflow, keras, model

When using a SimpleRNN or LSTM for classical sentiment analysis algorithms (applied here to sentences of length <= 250 words/tokens):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 32, input_length=250))   # Output shape: (None, 250, 32)
model.add(SimpleRNN(100))                          # Output shape: (None, 100)
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))          # Output shape: (None, 1)
```

where is it specified which axis of the input of the RNN is used as the "temporal" axis?

To be more precise, after the Embedding layer, a given input sentence, e.g. "the cat sat on the mat", is encoded into a matrix x of shape (250, 32), where 250 is the max length (in words) of the input text, and 32 the dimension of the embedding. Then, where in Keras is it specified if this will be used:

```
h[t] = activation( W_h * x[:, t] + U_h * h[t-1] + b_h )
```

or this:

```
h[t] = activation( W_h * x[t, :] + U_h * h[t-1] + b_h )
```

(In both cases, `y[t] = activation( W_y * h[t] + b_y )`)

TL;DR: if an input for a RNN Keras layer is of size, say, (250, 32), which axis does it use as the temporal axis by default? Where is this detailed in the Keras or Tensorflow documentation?

Comment: By default, it is the second axis. You can view the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) and [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SimpleRNN).

Answer (score 0):

The Equation, `h[t] = activation( W_h * x[t, :] + U_h * h[t-1] + b_h )` will be used by `Keras` or `Tensorflow`.

In this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SimpleRNN#call_arguments), it is mentioned that

`inputs: A 3D tensor, with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].`

We shall ignore the First Argument, `batch` and consider the rest of the Two Arguments for sometime.

In case of Sentiment Analysis, we can consider each `word/token` (converted to Vector) as a `Timestep`, as shown in the screenshot below.

In case of your example with Encoded Matrix with shape (250, 32), it means that each Review or Instance has 250 `words/tokens` or `Timesteps`.

So, the equation, `h[t] = activation( W_h * x[t, :] + U_h * h[t-1] + b_h )` can be translated as

**`h[t] = activation( W_h * x[Each Time Step/Word, All Features] + U_h * h[Previous Time Step/Word] + b_h )`**

[image]

Hope this clarifies your question. Happy Learning!